# Is there a Webhook for Modern Comments in SharePoint Online?

Tags: modern-experience, online, microsoft-graph, comments

Does anyone know if there are webhooks for the Modern SharePoint Online comments we can subscribe to?

[image]

We could not find anything useful yet and I suspect these webhooks don't exist, but I want to confirm that that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing that I see for comments on modern page is below API endpoint, which return all the comments on particular page (have tested)

```
/_api/web/lists('{PAGESLIBRARYGUID}')/GetItemById({PAGEITEMID})/Comments
```

Please see if you can subscribe to this endpoint or try subscribing to Library/ Page change and check if that triggers notification.

Unfortunately, it does not store comments in the SP list anymore :(

Reference article/ Discussion -

https://www.vrdmn.com/2017/07/working-with-page-comments-rest-api-in.html
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Alerts-on-Comments-in-Modern-Pages/td-p/130154